# CASE WHEN is giving 2 rows with duplicate ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a query which will produce the result as follows.

```
select t1.id as id,
CASE
    WHEN t3.key_id is not null and t3.key_id='SILICA'
    THEN t3.id
    END as SILICA_ID,
CASE
    WHEN t3.key_id is not null and t3.key_id='Mutual'
    THEN t3.id
    END as Mutual_ID
from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 
where t1.id=t2.t1_id and t2.id=t3.t2_id and t3.key_id in ('SILICA','Mutual') 
order by t1.id;
```

```
id     SILICA_ID      Mutual_id
==     =========      =========
1      null           1234
1      3456           null
2      null           7890
2      2374           null
2      4587           null
2      null           3489
```

But, I need a result as follows.

```
id     SILICA_ID      Mutual_id
==     =========      =========
1      3456           1234
2      2345           7890
2      4587           3489
```

how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do stop using comma seperated list as the from clause. Over 25 years ago a far better standard was adopted.  Time enough to change even for this silver ghost. Answer by trincot shows better syntax for joins

Comment: from **table** t1, **table** t2, **table** t3 ? What is this supposed to mean? Is this always the same table?

Comment: all are different tables.

Comment: Okay. Now please edit your request. So far you are showing a query result with two records for id 1 and two for id 2, and the result you really want (one row for id 1, one for id 2). Please show a query result with more rows for id 1 and again show the according desired result. Or better even make this a new request, as you already got correct answers for this one and even accepted one of them.

Comment: These are strange required results. Why do you combine silica 2345 with mutal 7890 and silica 4587 with mutual 3489? Why not silica 2345 with mutual 3489 for instance? What is the relation rule you are applying here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an aggregating solution such as

```
select id
       , max(silica_id) as silica_id
       , max(Mutual_ID) as Mutual_ID
from (
    select t1.id as id,
    CASE
        WHEN t3.key_id is not null and t3.key_id='SILICA'
        THEN t3.id
        END as SILICA_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN t3.key_id is not null and t3.key_id='Mutual'
        THEN t3.id
        END as Mutual_ID
    from table t1, table t2, table t3 
    where t1.id=t2.t1_id and t2.id=t3.t2_id and t3.key_id in ('SILICA','Mutual')
    ) 
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply on this. But, max(silica_id) will return the max id for this. For example, If  we are having 4 rows containing with respect to id, then max(silica_id) will return only the maximum value corresponding to that ID.

Comment: @Pamuleti Pullagura: Your sample data suggests that there is always only one `silica_id` per `t1.id`, so `max(silica_id)` will get this one value. If this is not always the case, you should edit your sample data with two different `silica_id` for `t1.id = 1` and show us what result you want then.

Comment: there are multiple silica_id's  per t1.id and multiple mutual_id's per t1.id..That is the problem..  "you should edit your sample data with two different silica_id for t1.id = 1 and show us what result you want then"..What exactly you are saying? can you explain more please?

Comment: You are complaining that my solution doesn't meet your needs. So please post data which **completely and accurately** reflects your situation. Edit your question with better raw data and revise the desired output so we can understand what you want.

Comment: Your solution is working for me. I am not complaining any thing. But, without using max function is there any other solution? As per your request, I have edited my query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `pivot` syntax for this:

```
select *
from   (
      select     t1.id, 
                 t3.id as t3_id, 
                 t3.key_id
      from       tabl t1
      inner join tabl t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
      inner join tabl t3 on t2.id = t3.t2_id
      where      t3.key_id in ('SILICA', 'Mutual')
) pivot (
      max(t3_id)
      for key_id in ('SILICA' as silica_id, 'Mutual' as mutual_id)
);
```

NB: It is a good habit to use the `join` clauses for expressing the join conditions, instead of putting them in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Can you tune this query without max() function?

Comment: The pivot syntax requires an aggregation. It provides the same output (unless I am mistaken) as the answer you accepted. The whole idea is that `id` should be unique in the output. If not, there is an ambiguity, and then I would ask you to provide example data and output for it to show how you would want that to work.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many `t2` per `t1` and many `t3` per `t2`. But you want one result row per `t1.id`. So you want to aggregate your data.

Your results show only one `t3.id` per `t1.id` and `t3.key_id`. This is unexpected and suggests either a wrong data model or unsufficent sample data.

Anyway, in order to get one result row per `t1.id` aggregate per `t1.id` and use conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.id as id,
  max(case when t3.key_id = 'SILICA' THEN t3.id end) as silica_id,
  max(case when t3.key_id = 'Mutual' then t3.id end) as mutual_id
from t1
join t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id 
join t3 on t3.t2_id = t2.id and t3.key_id in ('SILICA','Mutual') 
group by t1.id
order by t1.id;
```

**UPDATE:** Your altered request shows result rows, where the SILICA/Mutual pairs don't seem directly related. It seems you rather want to list them in a newspaper-like style. You can do this by selecting 'SILICA' and 'Mutual' separately, giving them row numbers and join on these.

```
select t1_id, s.t3_id as silica_id, m.t3_id as mutual_id 
  t1.id as t1_id, 
    t3.id as t3_id
(
  select distinct 
    t1.id as t1_id, 
    t3.id as t3_id,
    row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t3.id) as rn
  from t1
  join t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id 
  join t3 on t3.t2_id = t2.id and t3.key_id = 'SILICA'
) s
full outer join
(
  select distinct 
    t1.id as t1_id, 
    t3.id as t3_id,
    row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t3.id) as rn
  from t1
  join t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id 
  join t3 on t3.t2_id = t2.id and t3.key_id = 'Mutual'
) m using (t1_id, rn);
```

Comment: If I am using the max function, I may loss some other minimum records..Can you please tell me without max function?

Comment: Please see my altered answer. I suppose the new query is what you are looking for.